# Delete duplicates from binary tree

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, tree, binary-tree

Im trying to  come up with an algorithm for deleting duplicates from a binary tree/binary search tree. So far the best I could come up with was

> Store Inorder traversal of tree in an array.
>   If the tree has no ordering, sort the array.
>   remove duplicates from the array and reconstruct the binary tree.

Do we need to store the pre order traversal of the tree as well to reconstruct the tree?

This puts the complexity at  `O(n log n )`  time and `O(n)` space. Can we do better? Pseudo code / code samples would be appreciated

EDIT 1: Assume the structure of the binary tree is given by the following object

```
public class Node
{
   int data;
   Node right;
   Node left;
// getters and setters for the left and right nodes
}
```

Comment: A binary tree and a binary search tree would require completely different approaches.

Comment: Does it matter *how* you reconstruct the binary tree?  Note that an in order traversal will lose the original tree structure; anything resembling reconstruction would need to refer to the original tree (which is doable, just store a reference or index with the traversal data...).  In any case, you will need to specify what to do about deleted duplicates.

Comment: No. It doesnt matter how the tree is reconstructed .

Comment: I don't think you can beat the time complexity, but I have a more space efficient way to do it (see answer).

Comment: Then, you have nothing to lose by your approach.  Also, note: if the tree is already in order, an in-order traversal should yield a pre-sorted list of items, rendering the time complexity O(n) for that case.

Comment: There is insufficient information in the question to give anything better than a vague answer.  What is the input representation?  What are its invariants?  What constitutes a "duplicate"?  What are the required representation / invariants for the output tree?  (Same as the input tree?)

Comment: For instance your proposed "solution" seems to suggest that the input is NOT a binary search tree.

Comment: Yes. but it should work for both shouldnt it?

Comment: There are a ton of unknowns.  Is it array based? If not, what are there pointers to? Is it a BT, a BST, a BBST?  Do they care more about time or space?  You need to ask more questions.  This is too broad.  Your answer attempts to treat both solutions, which doesn't make sense.  If they say it can be many things, then you answer each independently...

Comment: I will try to add those details in the question.

Comment: @SteveP.: I would say that both time and space are important, but time complexity is  more important than space complexity.

Comment: There is a space complexity to time complexity trade off in this problem. You can do it in nlogn using my solution with space complexity O(logn). Using Hash table would do calculations in O(N) but recontrustion of BST would take O(NlogN).

Answer (score 3):

Remove duplicate algorithm for a Binary Search Tree:

1. Start a tree walk (in/pre/post order)
2. At each node, do a binary search on the subtree rooted at that node for the key value stored in the node.

   If the  key value is found down the tree, call delete(key) and restart step 2 (Might have multiple duplicates).

   Repeat step 2 until key not found in sub tree. Then go back to step 1

Time Complexity - `O(nlogn)` (For each of the `n` elements do a binary search which takes `logn` time)

Space Complexity - `O(logn)` (for the stack space used in the recursion)

Answer (score 0):

I have a weird idea:

If you already have a tree with duplicates and need to build the new one without duplicates then you can just:

1. Create empty hashmap of node values
2. Create new Tree
3. Traverse existing tree in any order and get elements one by one
4. If element is already present in hash map then do not add it to new
   tree

Is it ok?)

Comment: That's potentially a lot of extra space.

Comment: Yes, but all extra space is linear, so O(2*n) or O(3*n) is still O(n).

Comment: I understand, but my solution for example uses essentially no extra space.

Comment: @SteveP. I dont see your answer

Comment: @KodeSeeker Deleted it. Assumed an array implementation.

Comment: The recontruction tree is O(NlogN) i worst case still. But if more no of nodes are repeating then complexity reduces

Answer (score 0):

Proposed Recursive solution for your problem : -

```
deleteDup(Node p) {

  if(p == NULL) return

  else {

    deleteDup(p.left)
    deleteDup(p.right)
    delete(p.value,p.left)
    delete(p.value,p.right)

  } 

 }

 deleteDup(root)
```

Time complexity :

Deletion in BST = `O(logN)`

```
T(N) = 2T(N/2) + O(logN)
T(N) = O(N)
```

Space Complexity: `O(logN)`

**Note:-** Assuming balanced BST

Comment: The main question is, how the `delete` works? In this snippet you do not check at all, if is duplicate or not... Moreover @CodeKeeper did not assumed BST, so it does not answer his question.

Comment: @artur delete function does not delete any thing if value is not found in subtree and deletes if found(notice it can have only one occurrence as deleteDup have deleted other duplicates recursively). I think is insufficient info from OP that he is not given any specification. If the tree is not BST then in any case it is invalid after deletion and the question is how does he reconstruct it in his solution?. In that case his solution cannot be NlogN.

Answer (score 0):

I had another idea that runs in O(n) time and O(n) space.
For example, we have a tree with root A and two children A and B.
 A
A B

1. Create a Map counts that maps each value in the tree to a count.
2. Traverse all elements in the tree to populate counts. We will get counts[A]=2 and counts[B]=1. This takes O(n) space and O(n) time.
3. Again, traverse all elements in the tree. For every element, check if counts[element] > 1 and if so, we set counts[element]--, and delete that element (using binary tree deletion/rotation). This is O(n) time.
4. Once done, the tree has no more duplicates!

Answer (score 0):

I guess if child node equals to parent node, then we can try removing child node.

```
void travel(Node* root, int parentNode)
{
   if(root == NULL)
      return;
   if(root->val == parentNode)
      deleteNode(root, root->val) //method to remove node from BST
   travel(root->left, root->val);
   tarvel(root->right,root->val);
}

tarvel(root, INT_MIN);
```

Answer (score -2):

The trick in this situation is to not store the duplicates to start with....

When you add the nodes to the tree why can't you make the decision not to add the node if it already has a duplicate in the tree?

Comment: pseudocode: if(value > node) go_right else if(value<node) go_left else dont_insert_node.......

Comment: This was a programming question at one of the interviews, where the supplied tree already *had* duplicates in it

Comment: Relevant questions include:  was the tree in order beforehand or not?  What kind of structure or other properties (if any) should the deletion preserve?  If answers to these questions were not evident from the presentation of the question, it would be your job as interviewee to ask...